# Http Client correct way to pass content during post api call

Tags: c#, httpclient

Below is code snippet for POST api call where I am stuck with error:

> Bad request

After searching the web, I understand that you get this error when you don't follow proper payload syntax or pass proper payload data while making a post api call.

Here are different ways that I tried so far but unfortunately none work.

```
// payload data's class represantation,
    public class DNCAddressInfo
        {
            [JsonProperty("dncAddress")]
            public string DNCAddress { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("checkForPhoneRejection")]
            public bool CheckForPhoneRejection { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("checkForPhoneFormats")]
            public bool CheckForPhoneFormats { get; set; }
        }
```

**First try:**

```
DNCAddressInfo dncObj = GetPayloadData();
string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dncObj);
var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false); // response: error code: 400 , bad request
```

**Second try:**

```
    DNCAddressInfo dncObj = GetPayloadData();
JObject jsonObject = new JObject
            {
                ["dncAddress"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dncObj.DNCAddress),
                ["checkForPhoneRejection"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dncObj.CheckForPhoneRejection),
                ["checkForPhoneFormats"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dncObj.CheckForPhoneFormats)
            };

 var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);// response: error code: 400 , bad request
```

**Third try:**

```
string payload = "{\"dncAddress\": \"91#1231123\", \"checkForPhoneRejection\": false, \"checkForPhoneFormats\": false}"; // sample payload data taken from api providers document
var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false); // response: error code: 400 , bad request
```

All three approaches resulted in same error,

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: '400'

Request header is , 
Headers = {Authorization: Basic XXXXX;
Accept: application/json
X-Requested-With: rest
Cache-Control: no-cache
}
```

Response from Postman looks all fine. Here is snapshot of same.

[image: Postman response]

Is there anything I am doing wrong here or missing anything?

Comment: Could you try in postman or Rest Api client first to meet all requirements of the target Web API like Authorization, Content-Type, Payload,..

Comment: postman gives proper response when i use payload data which i mentioned in **Third try** of question. Headers looks all fine.

Comment: Don't you need to add a content-type header?

Comment: @jazza1000 as we are creating and passing `StringContent` data will do that job right?

Comment: @mabiyan - I would just have a careful look at what you are sending in fiddler and make sure all the headers match what you are sending in Postman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `PostJsonAsync` method, you don't need to manually serialize an object to json, just pass it as it is:

```
DNCAddressInfo dncObj = GetPayloadData();
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, dncObj).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

or you can use newer `HttpClient.PostAsync`:

```
DNCAddressInfo dncObj = GetPayloadData();
string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dncObj);
var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

References: **[HttpClient.PostAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=netframework-4.8)**, **[HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944682(v%3Dvs.118))**

Comment: i tried with both the ways you suggested, it ended up in with error : `System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError`

Comment: That's what your server returned, check your API with postman first.

Comment: i tried with postman, response looks all fine. I have just updated the snapshot of same in the post.

Comment: Check if data after serialization in the second example is the same as in postman.

Comment: Check your `_client` initialization, is the `BaseAddress` correct, also check value of `url`.

Comment: @SeM was getting `System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError` due to wrong content data. I was also using `{"dncAddress":"91#001G224908924U","checkForPhoneRejection":true,"checkForPhoneFormats":true}` while performing unit testing. Changed `dncAddress` value to `91#1231123` and tried _using POST call methods which you suggested here_ worked all fine. Thanks a-lot.

Answer (score 0):

"PostAsJsonAsync" method serializes data inside. When you pass "StringContent" to this method then HttpClient serializes "StringContent" to Json and sends wrong data.

Try to use "PostAsync" instead of "PostAsJsonAsync".